# List mapping of two different beans using MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

How can I do the bean mapping using MapStruct for the below scenario.
The entitlements property in both the classes is another bean with their own enum values. How to map these attributes?

```
@Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "email", source = "entity.email"),
        @Mapping(target = "displayName", source = "entity.displayName"),
        @Mapping(target = "entitlements", source = "entity.entitlements")
})
UserRequest userBeanToUserRequest(UserBean entity);


class UserRequest {
     private EmailAddress email;
     private String displayName;
     private List<EntitlementBean> entitlements;
}

class EntitlementBean {
     private EntitlementBean.EntitlementState entitlementState;
     private Map<String, String> properties;

     public static enum EntitlementState {
         ACTIVE,
         INACTIVE;
     }
}

class UserRequest {
     private EmailAddress email;
     private String displayName;
     private List<EntitlementRequest> entitlements;
}

class EntitlementRequest {
     private EntitlementRequest.EntitlementState entitlementState;
     private Map<String, String> properties;

     public static enum EntitlementState {
         ACTIVE,
         INACTIVE;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that MapStruct will complain that it can't map `EntitlementBean.EntitlementState` with `EntitlementRequest.EntitlementState`. When this happens it will show what you need to do in the error message.

In this case you need to provide a mapping between enums. You can read more about it in [Mapping Values](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-enum-types).

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    UserRequest userBeanToUserRequest(UserBean entity);

    EntitlementBean.EntitlementState mapState(EntitlementRequest.EntitlementState state);

}
```

I removed the `@Mapping` from the `userBeanToUserRequest` since they are obsolete, MapStruct will do implicit mapping when the names of the properties matches.